# Using RAII with C++ streams and STL containers?

Tags: c++, stl, raii, iostream

I'm trying to use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) concepts with an STL container of ofstream objects.  For example:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::deque<std::ofstream> sList;

  sList.push_back(std::ofstream()); // tried variations such as *(new ofstream())
  sList[0].open("test1.txt");
  sList[0] << "This is a test";
  sList[0].close();
}
```

However, no matter how I try to tweak the code and declarations, the compiler always complains.  Apparently the copy constructor for std::basic_ios, which lives inside of streams, is private.  Are there any easy plian C++/STL solutions to doing this using RAII, or do I need to get some type of smart pointer involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interest of keeping a file from being written to in multiple places in various parts of the system, streams are noncopyable.  A smart pointer is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Though all the answers here have good info, I liked your answer because it explains the rationale as to WHY a file stream is not copyable.  Well done!

Answer (score 5):

Standard library containers store copies of the values, not the values themselves. As such, you *will* have to use an object that can be copied (a smart pointer in this case).

An alternative would be `boost::ptr_vector` which acts as a vector of pointers precisely for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4):

Stream objects cannot be copied, so you can't create containers of them - you will have to use pointers of some sort.

```
deque <ofstream *> files;
files.push_back( new ofstream );
// and later delete it, or use a smart pointer
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to get a smart pointer of some sort involved. One of the requirements of containers (at least in C++) is that to put something in a container, it must be copyable -- and streams are *not* copyable.

FWIW, in C++0x, this will be possible directly -- it allows containers to hold items that are movable but not copyable, and streams will be movable (but still not copyable).

Comment: Interesting point about C++11, which, fast-forward 3+ years, has now become relevant.

Answer (score 2):

ofstream has RAII baked in. The destructor of ofstream automagically closes the files so you don't need to.

Use

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>>
```

as your container and all the file handles will be deleted when you drop the vector.

Do not use a container of std::auto_ptr!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with std::auto_ptr. Just don't use it for things it is not meant to be used for. auto_ptr moves the contained pointer on copy. So if you have.

http://gist.github.com/498683

When p goes out of scope it deletes the object foo.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with auto_ptr. It has specific use case and you just need to know the appropriate time and place where to use it.

Comment: I should have qualified my statement.  Since a lot of STL (including containers) makes copies of the objects being used, auto_ptr is not a good fit in this situation, since no two auto_ptrs should own the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using boost::ref. It's meant to store references without copying them.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/ref.htm

Comment: And where to store the actual streams?

Comment: Where you create them.
{
  std::ofstream stream;
  {
    std::deque<boost::ref<std::ofstream>> sList;
    sList.push_back(boost:ref(stream));
    ...
  }
  // Stream is destroyed.
}

Comment: And how does it help the asker?

Comment: No need for a copy constructor, which was the problem.

Comment: But how do references extend the lifetime of the temporaries in the original example (`sList.push_back(std::ofstream());`)? To make it short: What you propose is a fixed size container of references to fixed objects, whereas it appears to me that the asker wants to organize an arbitrary number of file-streams. I can't imagine a use case for your proposal that conforms to the classy 1-0-infinity principle, even though mentioning boost::ref is nice.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's only a partial answer to the original question. But since he asked about copy-construction, this can help him sometimes. But I totally agree it does not solve his original problem.

Comment: Sorry for being picky in that Q/A-style; but I found that sometimes, answering such picky questions enlightened me. Have a good weekend, btw :)

Comment: It's ok (and was kind of challenging in fact since it was an answer so old I did not remember answering it). Have a nice weekend too :-)

Comment: @Scharron that is so funny to me...only because I've been there!